# Windows Authentication in IIS - ban local users from MVC4 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication

We are using IIS 7-8 for our MVC4 application. The access is protected by the IIS built-in Windows Authentication. The local users (added on the server) and the users registered in the AD are able to log in. How can I exclude the local users from the ability to log in?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to build the authentication based on *AD Groups*.

You create one or more *AD Groups* and add the users you want to that group(s). Then you can limit the access to your web application to those groups only.

Then in MVC you can use the `Authorize` attribute on your Actions, Controllers, or set it as global filter.

Basic usage

```
[Authorize(Roles=@"MyCompanyDomain\\company-group-name-here")]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem here: The solution should accept any domains without a fixed definition.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution via my MVC4 C# Code:

```
public static bool IsLocalUser(WindowsIdentity pIdentity)
{
    // establish domain context         
    PrincipalContext lMachineContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);

    // find user
    UserPrincipal lMachineUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(lMachineContext, pIdentity.Name);

    return lMachineUser != null;
}
```

In my controller, call the method and pass the identity:

```
if(IsLocalUser(HttpContext.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity))
{
    // block and refer to error site.
}
```